# Stack of Activities in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

I am noob in android. I want to know that Does android keep multiple `Stack` for the activities for a single application ?? If it so then for what reason it keep multiple stacks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, android does keep multiple tasks stack : http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html

A task is composed of many activities, sometimes from differnt programs. A task is a user task. For instance this allows you to

- have a task that browse the web with a browser
- have a task to write an email

you can then switch from one task to the other, for instance to copy paste a phone number from the web into an email. You will switch tasks by long-pressing the home button and get a list of all current tasks.

Comment: I have updated my question, please see - `Does android keep multiple Stack for the activities for a single application ??`

Comment: Yes it can if you precise that activities are run in different tasks.